# Ошибка в выводе результата (alert)

Tags: javascript

- Всем хай, есть функция, которая выводит наименьшее число из двух,
- по идеи **alert** должен вывести результат, но он почему-то не выводит.
- Где я допустил ошибку(?

```js
function min(a, b) {
 a = +prompt('a', '');
 b = +prompt('b', '');
  
  if (a < b) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return b;
  }

alert(min(a,b));
};


min();
```

Comment: `return` прерывает выполнение функции. До alert не доходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
    function min(a, b) {
        if (a < b) {
            return a;
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    }
    let a = +prompt('a', '');
    let b = +prompt('b', '');
    alert(min(a,b));
```

или так:

```js
    function min() {
        let a = +prompt('a', '');
        let b = +prompt('b', '');
        if (a < b) {
            return a;
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    }

    alert(min());
```

Comment: Ваша функция работает без вызова? Обычно же надо вызывать функцию запрашивая ее имя в данном случае  * min(); *
Объясните нубу(((

Comment: @Black_Viper Вы можете либо передавать параметры в функцию, как в первом примере, но тогда Вам необходимо объявить эти переменные и передать их функцию. То-есть параметры `a` и `b` выносите за функцию. Либо Вы можете в самой функции объявить переменные и уже работать с ними в ней, вернув только то, значение, которое хотите. В этом случае Вам нет необходимости передавать в функцию значения, так как они и так объявляются и появляются внутри самой функции )

Comment: Благодарствую сударт)))
Если не секрет, то скажите пожалуйста, 
сколько лет вы изучаете javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не туда закрывающую скобку у функции min поставили (после alert). Надо так (до alert):

```
function min() {
  a = +prompt('a', '');
  b = +prompt('b', '');

  if (a < b) {
    return a;
  } else {
    return b;
  }
}

alert(min());
```

И prompt лучше вызывать до функции min - так логичнее

```
function min(a, b) {
  return a < b? a: b;           
}

var a = +prompt('a', '');
var b = +prompt('b', '');

alert(min(a, b));
```

Comment: Не работает ваш вариант((

Comment: Браузер показывает, что ошибка, где alert(min(a,b));

Comment: @Black_Viper у вас скопипастнул )) Без аргументов должен быть, конечно, если prompt  внутри

Comment: @Black_Viper исправил, укоротил тернарным оператором

Comment: А как играет Prompt на аргументы? Почему нельзя прописать аргументы в функции? Объясните нубу)))

Comment: @Black_Viper Лучше почитайте вот тут https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics

Comment: Там нет ответа на мой вопрос((( Там не написано почему нельзя ставить аргументы, если внутри функции есть prompt((((

Comment: @Black_Viper там описано все про аргументы функции. Кто вам сказал, что нельзя вызывать prompt внутри фукции? Просто в вашем случае это не логично. А ошибка было потому, что аргументы a и b при вызове min  нигде не были определены заранее, вот и все